# Determining of Fracture Toughness without fatigue pre cracking, is it possible?

Tags: material-science

Determining of Fracture Toughness without fatigue pre cracking, is it possible?
I want to find the consistent method for determining fracture toughness values without fatigue test for creating starting micro cracks

Answer (score 1):

These two methods are the most widely used and known. Very quick, easy and fun to do (unlike fatigue testing!) All universities with an engineering department will have the apparatus.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Izod_impact_strength_test

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charpy_impact_test